# node.js: looping, email each matching row from query but it it emails the same user by # number of matches?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, email, row

I have a node.js email server that works fine however I noticed a problem. If the query string found 4 rows, it would send four emails but only to the first result instead of to each found email address.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// Amazon SES is sending the emails - uses this module for node
var ses = require('nodemailer-ses-transport');
//transport for connecting with Amazon SES
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(ses({
accessKeyId: '****************',
SecretAccessKey: '*************'
}));

// Mysql Connection to database
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
*****connection info goes here *****
});
//Connect to mysql database and check for errors
connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;}
  });

var querystring1 = 'SELECT `date_created`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`email` FROM `users` WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,date_created, NOW()) <=298 AND `email`!="" LIMIT 0,5';

connection.query(querystring1, function (err, row) {
if (err) throw err;
for (var i in row) {
// Email content; change text to html to have html emails. row[i].column name will pull relevant database info
var sendit = {
    to: row[i].email,
    from: '******@******',
    subject: 'Hi ' + row[i].first_name + ', Thanks for joining ******!',
    html:  {path:__dirname + '/templates/welcome.html'}
};

// Send emails
transporter.sendMail(sendit,function(error,response){
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);

    }else{
    console.log("Message sent1: " + row[i].first_name);}
transporter.close();}
)
}});
```

....

How do I have it loop through each found row and send a custom email using row data individual row data?

Comment: your log message will probably always print the last one, since the sendMail callback is called after the loop ends and var i is defined at upper function scope and holds the last iteration index (javascript doesn't have block scope).

it is still possible however that the mails were sent to 4 different indivituals

Comment: I thought so, but I had this strange problem where some of the triggered emails would come as doubles when sent to me for testing. I thought it was a bot(nope), timezone overlap(nope), and now it makes sense.... it was sending repeat mails becuase the query detected two rows, but skipped the 2nd user's row info....it just repeated the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not close the transporter until all your emails are sent.

```
var querystring1 = 'SELECT `date_created`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`email` FROM `users` WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,date_created, NOW()) <=298 AND `email`!="" LIMIT 0,5';

connection.query(querystring1, function (err, row) { if (err) throw err; 
var toSend=[];
for (var i in row) { // Email content; change text to html to have html emails. 
toSend.push({//row[i].column name will pull relevant database info 
    to: row[i].email,
    from: '******@******',
    subject: 'Hi ' + row[i].first_name + ', Thanks for joining ******!',
    html:  {path:__dirname + '/templates/welcome.html'} 
 });
}

// Send emails
 async.eachSeries(toSend, function( sendit, callback) {
    transporter.sendMail(sendit,function(error,response){

        if (error) {
        callback(error);

         }else{
        console.log("Message sent1: " + sendit.to); callback();
         }
     )},function(err){if (err) throw (err); console.log("Finished")};
 });
});
```

Comment: Didn't work, still selects the first result and just blasts them for each match

Comment: @udonsoup16 Let me think about it and come back to you. Something minor but remove the last ',' here: html:  {path:__dirname + '/templates/welcome.html'},
};

Comment: @udonsoup16 Give it a try without closing the transporter. This will help you to know if this is the transporter you are closing too early or something else.

Comment: Not the most beautiful solution but you could try with async.js using a forEach element. I'll edit my answer with it in some minutes.

Comment: Nope, async did not work but it's definately a module I will be using in the future.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the output and the transporter initialization?

Comment: Edited it. Added that and the modules

Comment: Could you please tell me the output you get using the code I just provided? Also if you use amazon. Do this: var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var ses = require('nodemailer-ses-transport');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(ses({
    accessKeyId: 'AWSACCESSKEY',
    secretAccessKey: 'AWS/Secret/key'
}));

Comment: the console log grabs the first matching query name: Message sent1: BAHAR and then repeats it until the limit(5) since I changed the query to find nearly every query older than 5 minutes for test purposes. Nothing has changed since the oringinal code I presented.

Comment: just tested my code and it was working. Please do a console.log(row) and check these are array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
// Send emails
(function (mail) {
    transporter.sendMail(mail,function(error,response){
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            console.log("Message sent1: " + mail.first_name);}
            transporter.close();
        }
    )
)(sendit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this one, I have tested and it works fine:

```
function sendmail(sendit, username){
  transporter.sendMail(sendit,function(error,response){
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log("Message sent: " + username);}
      transporter.close();
    }
  )
};


for (var i in row) {
  var sendit = {
    to: row[i].email,
    from: 'sandeepv@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Hi ' + row[i].first_name + ', Thanks for joining!',
    html:  {path:__dirname + '/welcome.html'},
  };

  // Send email
  sendmail(sendit, row[i].first_name);
}
```